# Probability of matches

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The probability of a team winning a match is $\frac{4}{7}$, it losing the match is $\frac{2}{7}$ and it having a draw is $\frac{1}{7}$. If there are 40 matches, then what is the probability that the team has 25 wins, 10 losses and 5 draws?

I think the answer should be 
$$\frac {40!}{25!10!5!}\cdot \left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^{25}\cdot \left(\frac{2}{7}\right)^{10}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^{5},$$
but I am not sure. This is a result of a trinomial expansion of $\left(\frac{4}{7} +\frac{2}{7}+\frac{1}{7}\right)^{40}$.

Comment: Hint: Please look under [multinomial distribution.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution)

Comment: I have an approach in mind but dont know if its correct.

Comment: Well you should post your attempt even though it might not be correct,it will be easier to point to a mistake in your work if you have it.

Comment: @kingW3 I think that the terms of the trinomial expansion I have typed above are probabilities of various combinations of wins losses and draws. The particular term which I have posted should be the solution of this problem according to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could think of it as breaking the required event into the following three operations:

1) Choosing 25 of the 40 to be wins in $\binom{40}{25}$ ways

2) Choosing 10 of the remaining 15 to be losses in $\binom{15}{10}$

3) Choosing 5 of the remaining 5 to be draws in 1 way

These operations are preformed together in $\binom{25}{40}$*$\binom{15}{10}*1$=$\frac { 40! }{ 25!10!5! }$ ways with each instance having probability $({ \frac { 4 }{ 7 } ) }^{ 25 }*{ (\frac { 2 }{ 7 } ) }^{ 10 }*{ (\frac { 1 }{ 7 } ) }^{ 5 }$. Then, as you noted, the probability that the event occurs is $$\frac { 40! }{ 25!10!5! }* ({ \frac { 4 }{ 7 } ) }^{ 25 }*{ (\frac { 2 }{ 7 } ) }^{ 10 }*{ (\frac { 1 }{ 7 } ) }^{ 5 }$$

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct, due to independence of events and he fact that the order of events is not important.

you need to select 25 out of 40, 10 fro 15 amd 5 out of 5. You get $\binom{40}{25} \binom{15}{10} \binom{5}{5} $.